# Check Facebook Login in Android

Tags: android

I have an application that uses the Facebook SDK for Android to login into my application. But I am having some problems in checking whether the user is already logged-in or not. After the login page, the main interface will be displayed to the user. What I want is that, if the user  has logged-in in its past interaction with application, the next time the application is launched, no more login screen just the main interface. So at start-up my application should check whether a user is logged in or not. How will I do it?

I tried using `mFacebook.isSessionValid()`, but it's always returning a false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can try the following code :**

```
if(mFacebook.isSessionValid()) {
onFacebookClick();
}

private void onFacebookClick() {
        if (mFacebook.isSessionValid()) {
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("Delete current Facebook connection?")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                fbLogout();
                                }
                            })
                    .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                                facebook_btn.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.signinout));
                                }
                            });
            final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        } else {
            facebook_btn.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.signin));
            mFacebook.authorize(this, PERMISSIONS, -1,new FbLoginDialogListener());
        }
    }
```